# Data Warehouse - Storing unique data over time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse

Basically we are building a reporting dashboard for our software. We are giving the Clients the ability to view basic reporting information.

Example: (I've removed 99% of the complexity of our actual system out of this example, as this should still get across what I'm trying to do)

One example metric would be...the number of unique products viewed over a certain time period. AKA, if 5 products were each viewed by customers 100 times over the course of a month. If you run the report for that month, it should just say 5 for number of products viewed.

Are there any recommendations on how to go about storing data in such a way where it can be queried for any time range, and return a unique count of products viewed. For the sake of this example...lets say there is a rule that the application cannot query the source tables directly, and we have to store summary data in a different database and query it from there.

As a side note, we have tons of other metrics we are storing, which we store aggregated by day. But this particular metric is different because of the uniqueness issue.

I personally don't think it's possible. And our current solution is that we offer 4 pre-computed time ranges where metrics affected by uniqueness are available. If you use a custom time range, then that metric is no longer available because we don't have the data pre-computed.

Comment: I am wondering...instead of saving the summary data somewhere else, how about defining a VIEW that returns the count of items (or whatever the summary data is) and apply the date-range filter on the view? Or even better...define a stored procedure that applies the SELECT statement based on date range (passed as parameter) on the source data.

Comment: We need to precalc and store this data because we are running it for millions and millions of rows, so to generate this data on the fly every time a client runs the report would take a very long time. On a client by client basis, it only takes seconds, which isn't bad. But this data is also being used for benchmarking (comparing one client to groups of other clients), which when being run for thousands of clients at a time, it takes WAY to long to calc on the fly. Using our pre-calced database, the other metrics only take fractions of a second to aggregate thousands of clients a time.

Comment: Which data warehouse methodology are you using, Inmon or Kimball?

Comment: I have no idea. But I feel that is outside the scope of the question. I'm looking for a high-level answer on how to go about storing data in a SQL database to accomplish what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to change the grain of the fact table. This can't be done.

Your best option is what I think you are doing now - define aggregate fact tables at the grain of day, week and month to support your performance constraint.

You can address the custom time range simply by advising your users that this will be slower than the standard aggregations. For example, a user wanting to know the counts of unique products sold on Tuesdays can write a query like this, at the expense of some performance loss:

```
select  distinct dim_prod.pcode
        ,count(*)
from    fact_sale
        join dim_prod on dim_prod.pkey = fact_sale.pkey
        join dim_date on dim_date.dkey = fact_sale.dkey
where   dim_date.day_name = 'Tuesday'
group by dim_prod.pcode
```

The query could also be written against a daily aggregate rather than a transactional fact, and as it would be scanning less data it would run faster, maybe even meeting your need

Answer (score 0):

From the information that you have provided, I think you are trying to measure ' number of unique products viewed over a month (for example)'.

Not sure if you are using Kimball methodologies to design your fact tables. I believe in Kimball methodology, an Accumulating Snapshot Fact table will be recommended to meet such a requirement.

I might be preaching to the converted(apologies in that case), but if not then I would let you go through the following link where the experts have explained the concept in detail: 
http://www.kimballgroup.com/2012/05/design-tip-145-time-stamping-accumulating-snapshot-fact-tables/

I have also included another link from Kimball, which explains different types of fact tables in detail:

http://www.kimballgroup.com/2014/06/design-tip-167-complementary-fact-table-types/

Hope that explains the concepts in detail. More than happy to answer any questions(to the best of my ability)

Cheers
Nithin